# Download PDF file from google drive AppScript Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I created a button in google sheets and I'm trying to download file from google drive with ID that I store in a cell. I searched stackoverflow and I found some code that might work, but it doesn't. When I assign the script to the button and I click it, it says "We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again."

That's the code I'm trying to use:

```
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(downloader());
}

function downloader() {
  var mySheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("File Lookup");
  var File_LinkID = mySheet.getRange("J4").getValue();

  var out = "<body onload='dllink.click()'>";
  out +="<a id='dllink' href='https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id="+File_LinkID+"'>wait will download automatically<a/>";
  out +="</body>";
  return out;
};
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In your situation, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
out +="<a id='dllink' href='https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id="+File_LinkID+"'>wait will download automatically<a/>";
```

#### To:

```
out +="<a id='dllink' target='_blank' href='https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id="+File_LinkID+"'>wait will download automatically<a/>";
```

- In this modification, `target='_blank'` is added.

#### Note:

- If an error is related to the permission, please publicly share the file and test it again.
- In your script, it seems that Web Apps is used. **In this case, when you modified the Google Apps Script, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful this.**
- You can see the detail of this in the report of "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".

Comment: I tried what you said. And when I go to Deploy -> Test Deployment, there I can see my web app and URL to script. I click the script and I can download the file.
But, when I assign the function "doGet" to my button in google sheet, I get the message : We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again.

Comment: @ktos1234 Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, when I tested my proposed modification, I confirmed that your modified script works. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. In order to correctly replicate your situation, can you provide your script for replicating the issue? By this, I would like to confirm it. By the way, `File_LinkID` is the URL of PDF file. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, File_LinkID is the ID of google drive's PDF file. I just need a button in my google sheet, that download PDF file that is stored in Google Drive. I have ID of all PDF files in my google sheet.

Comment: @ktos1234 Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, when I tested my proposed modification, I confirmed that your modified script works. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. In order to correctly replicate your situation, can you provide your script for replicating the issue? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: Hi there @ktos1234! If you still can't implement this answer in your scenario, could you please clarify that error? Does it appear on new Apps Script projects? Does it replicate with different PDF files?